# Retain SourceViewController after custom push segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I've got a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` called `leftToRightSegue`. Every time this segue is triggered and I move back to the source view, the `viewdidload` method of the `sourceViewController` is called. This is not something I want, since the setup is quite heavy.

This is the code I'm using for the segue:

```
#import "LeftToRightPushSegue.h"
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"

@implementation LeftToRightPushSegue

-(void)perform {

    UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = .25;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;

    [sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                                                forKey:kCATransition];

    [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];

}
```

I am in fact popping the view back, for anyone interested:

```
UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];

CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = .25;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;

[sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                                            forKey:kCATransition];

[sourceViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

How do I retain the sourceViewController?

Comment: A `UIViewController`'s `-viewDidLoad` is called when the view hierarchy is loaded into memory from a nib or programmatically. Post more code, the problem can be in your call to `-sourceViewController`.

Comment: Do you mean to post the pop segue? The above code is all for the push

Comment: Could you provide more code around `[sourceViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];`. It's not clear where it's called and how it get pointer at `sourceViewController`.

Comment: May be it should be `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]` instead.

Comment: Interesting call there! Updated the code too :)

Comment: @Cy-4AH trowing a compiler error.

Comment: Ah. I get it. You created another custom segue for returning back. And Storyboard creating new instance. You need unwind segue for this purpose.

Comment: Hm usually is a pop segue good enough. Why should I need unwind in this case vs just push/pop?

Comment: How you noticed: pop segues is not good enough. Any not unwind segue will create destinationViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to move the code to the init method if possible. 
If that's not possible, perhaps create a boolean property. i.e.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) BOOL *isInitialised;



- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    if (!self.isInitialised) 
    {
       ...
       self.isInitialised = YES;
    }
}
```

You set it to true once the actions in the viewDidLoad have been performed. There are better patterns if you search a little. This is a bit of quick and dirty way of getting it to work.

Also keep in mind that you'll be keeping in memory stuff, not directly visible to the user.